# UK short-term study visa sponsored by family

Tags: visas, uk, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm studying in my second year at unviersity. I will apply for short-term study visa to study General English for two weeks in Liverpool.

- My sponsor is my brother: his salary is 400 pounds per month. He gets paid via the post office, and he has 2800 pounds in his bank account which is now one month old.
- I will pay study and accomodation fees with a total of 900 pounds and get a Visa letter from school.
- My brother will transfer 980 pounds from his bank account to mine one month before applying to visa.

Will I get my visa accepted?

Comment: Unfortunately no-one can answer that for certain. On the face of it, the financial circumstances you’re describing don’t look favourable. You should read https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e and https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673351/Visit-guidance-v7.0EXT.PDF before deciding whether to continue with your application

Comment: Do no transfer money between accounts. This is money parking, and will not help you.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi i will do transfert from my sponsor's bank account to mine and hold the funds in my account for 28 days and after that i will print account statement and put it in my application in order to prove my source of incomes, it's okay like that?

Comment: @Traveller what is the reason that i will be refused for, if i apply with these options ?and can i correct it if i reapply in the future?

Comment: @Steven Paul You can be refused if UKVI don’t think you have sufficient funds available to you or if they think the amount you’re planning to spend on the trip is disproportionate to your income, or if they decide they can’t assess your financial situation because you haven’t provided sufficient bank statements (typically 6 months’ worth). You can be refused if they think you are a flight risk if you can’t prove you have a travel history or strong enough ties to home. Read the question I linked to above.

Comment: @StevenPaul: no, it is not ok. It is money parking. All people do it, so having just one statement with funds and no real proof of income is not sufficient. They handle thousands of visa so they know way better. Never lie, never cheat on such official things. You may get troubles later on getting in other countries. Personal opinion: if I were the officer, I'll deny to you the visa, thinking I'll do it for good of you and your brother.